# Understand the is null query in sql

Tags: sql, null

I have a table with 3 rows, where i did fill all the collumns with atributes. I can't understand why when i do this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM person WHERE NULL is NULL;
```

it gives me the result: 3.
can you please explain me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, `NULL = NULL` is not true. However, `NULL IS NULL` is indeed true, and equivalent to `1=1`. Therefore, you get all the rows.

For example, as per MSDN documentation for SQL Server:

> If the value of expression is NULL, IS NULL returns TRUE; otherwise, it returns FALSE.
>
> If the value of expression is NULL, IS NOT NULL returns FALSE; otherwise, it returns TRUE.

Here, the value `NULL` is a valid expression for `IS NULL`, and so returns `TRUE`. Therefore, you get all the rows from table.

Answer (score 3):

Because for every row condition

```
NULL is NULL
```

is always true, so there is no reason to filter the rows.

Below condition could be the opposite of above condition

```
1=0
```

with this condition you will get 0 rows because for every row the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

'WHERE NULL is NULL' is the condition that you are using, and it is always true, for that reason it retrieves all the 3 results.